# How to add a new project type to IronPython Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython, vsx

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961%28VS.100%29.aspx), but it only describes how to add a new project type based on C#. I want to create a new project (sub)type underneath IronPython.

I've downloaded the IronPython source code, and I think I've found the place where I need to add my new template, but I don't know how to "run" it. VS tells me I can't run the project because it's a class. When following the above tutorial, it actually *does* let you run it, it just fires up a test instance of VS. So how would I test my new IronPython template? When I build it, it creates a `dll` and a `vsix` file, but I don't know what to do with them.

I can copy the `template.zip` file into my VS ProjectTemplates folder, and that works, but I need to add some more functionality than just a template, which is why I'm trying to create a VSPackage. The IronPython source does this, but I just need to find the proper way to extend it.

Also, I'd preferably like to decouple my project with the `IronPythonTools` project so that I don't have to rebuild the whole thing, and when IronPythonTools is updated, my project won't explode. There must be some kind of class I can inherit from instead?

Answer (score 1):

When you build and get the VSIX file you can use that to install the package into a normal instance of VS.  You just need to double click on the .vsix file and you'll get the VS extension installation experience.  You can also give the VSIX to anyone else and they can install it as well.

The easiest way to be decoupled from IronPython Tools would be to not link against any of it's assemblies.  That might mean you need to create some functionality from scratch if you're using anything that's in Ipy Tools.

Comment: I tried double clicking it... it did install, but that's not very good for development. I made some changes and tried installing it again, and now it's telling me it's already been installed. I'm also not sure how to *uninstall* it now. By "decouple" I just mean that it should be easy to update IronPython without my app falling apart... it will be dependent on IronPython in some ways, because it's a Python framework I'm trying to build. I just want it to be nested under "IronPython" when you go to create a new project... I don't know if I configure that in one of the XML files...

Comment: Or if it's in one of those .cs classes... I guess I have to delve into it a bit more. I'm just struggling to follow these tutorials just to get something compiled! Figured it would be a lot easier to get something basic up, I haven't even done any customization yet.

Comment: To uninstall you need to go to Tools->Extension Manager in VS and tell it to uninstall.

Comment: To uninstall you need to go to Tools->Extension Manager in VS and tell it to uninstall.

Comment: To get the project to show up under IronPython your .vstemplate file should have a <ProjectType>IronPython</ProjectType>